# After throwing a Security Exception, redirect to Login page

Tags: webforms, asp.net-membership, asp.net-routing, securityexception, webforms-routing

I'm using WebForms and Asp.Net Routing.

When trying to implement security on a members folder, I'm following the directions here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/06/21/asp-net-routing-and-authorization.aspx

```
  private IHttpHandler GeneratePage(string VN, RequestContext RC)
  {
    string virtualPath
      = string.Format("~/Members/{0}.aspx", VN);

    if (UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(virtualPath,
      RC.HttpContext.User,
      RC.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod))
    {
      if (virtualPath != null)
      {
        return (Page)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new SecurityException();
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

However, I don't just want to throw a security Exception, I would like to redirect to the login page. I'd rather not hard-code a `Response.Redirect` and I don't think this is the right way to do it anyhow.

What's the "proper" way to pass control to the Authorization engine and redirect to the Default Login page?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have both.

Thowing an exception terminates the code path.

Alternatively you can call
`FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(string extraQueryString)` and pass an arg that lets you inform the user of the problem on the login page.

e.g.

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage("error=authorization-failure")`

You would, of course, need to write code in the login page to recognize this.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why you'd want to just throw a Security error in this space, but I was assuming you would do the redirect in a `catch` block.

Comment: @Atømix - it all depends on who is doing the catching. you said you wanted to throw and redirect. the only way you can do that is if you are doing the catching and if this is the case, it is not an exception, it is an expected case and should have an appropriate code path. You would throw an exception if there is nothing that you can do about the state.